# How to detect user's browser type in server side (node js) from an api call?

Tags: angular, express

I need to distinguish between a desktop browser rest API calls and mobile browser(mostly tablets) rest API calls. 
I am using node express on my server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the user-agent by looking into `req.headers[user-agent]`.